# Print Gives Unlimited Pages

Tags: c#, .net, loops, printing

Below is a Method which prints Testing string. I am unable to figure out why this gives unlimited new pages with same contents. I need to print a new page after 30th round.

```
private void PrintSetup(Graphics g, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e) 
    {
        float linesPerPage = 0;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        float rightMargin = e.MarginBounds.Right;
        float bottomMargin = e.MarginBounds.Bottom;
        float Height = e.MarginBounds.Height;
        float Width = e.MarginBounds.Width;
        float FontHeight = NormalFont.GetHeight();

        linesPerPage = Height / NormalFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

        while (count < linesPerPage)
        {

            g.DrawString("Test   " + count, NormalFont, BlackBrush, leftMargin, topMargin + Line(count));

            if (count > 30)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;
            }

            count++;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Because you start at count = 0 for every page.  You need to store that in a field of your class instead of a local variable.  And initialize it to 0 with the BeginPrint event.

Comment: thanks but after adding 'count=0' it freezes print preview. i did add it on the BeginPrint event also. no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Everyone for Answering me... After long long time i founded what happened.. and the below code works fine.

Which will Create a new page if the count goes out of bounds.

Hope this will help for the beginners. thanks

```html
_Line = 0; 

void printDocument1_PrintPage( object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e )
                
            {

                float lineHeight = NormalFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics) + 4;
     
                    float yLineTop = e.MarginBounds.Top;
                    yLineTop = yLineTop + 100;

                    for ( ; _Line <= 100 ; _Line++ )
                    {

                        if ( yLineTop + lineHeight > e.MarginBounds.Bottom )
                        {
                            e.HasMorePages = true;
                            return;
                        }
     
                        e.Graphics.DrawString( "TEST: " + _Line, NormalFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF( e.MarginBounds.Left, yLineTop ) );

                        yLineTop += lineHeight;

                    }

                    e.HasMorePages = false;
              
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never reset `count` once you reached 30.

Comment: thanks but after adding 'count=0' it freezes print preview. i did add it on the BeginPrint event also. no luck.